# An app.js file for every feature in my electron web app

Tags: angularjs, electron

I am grouping my electronjs(angular,mysql) application files based on feature, for example, I am developing an inventory system, and this is how I organized my file:

```
 /app

  /scripts

       /categories
             -- app.js
             -- category.html
             -- categoryController.js
             -- categoryService.js (MySQL data access procedures)

      / brands
             -- app.js
             -- brands.html
             -- brandsController.js
             -- brandsService.js (MySQL data access procedures)

      / unitsofmeasure
             -- app.js
             -- unitsofmeasure.html
             -- unitsofmeasureController.js
             -- unitsofmeasureService.js (MySQL data access procedures)

      / products
      / suppliers
      ....
```

and so on for each feature.

Inside each app.js file (example for category):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var _templateBase = './scripts';    

    angular.module('app', [
        'ngRoute',
        'ngMaterial',
        'ngAnimate'        
    ])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: _templateBase + '/category/category.html' ,
                controller: 'categoryController',
                controllerAs: '_ctrl'
            });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        }
    ]) ;            
})();
```

My question: is it ok to have several app.js file for each feature my app would have?

Comment: I'm also developing a similar inventory system using Electron. Do you have any reference projects urls ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow DRY practice or don't repeat yourself. Therefore the best way to put it is to create a module outside those folders for all the subfolders. What I mean is that you create module.js or whatever you want to name it in root of scripts folder. Inside module.js you can just create a module that you will use later or you can include all configuration.

First way:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';  

  angular.module('app', [
      'ngRoute',
      'ngMaterial',
      'ngAnimate'        
  ])

})();
```

And then inside each folder file for routing (maybe categoriesConfig.js...):

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var _templateBase = './scripts';    

  angular.module('app')
  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
              templateUrl: _templateBase + '/category/category.html' ,
              controller: 'categoryController',
              controllerAs: '_ctrl'
          });
          $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
      }
  ]) ;            
})();
```

Second way:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var _templateBase = './scripts';    

  angular.module('app', [
      'ngRoute',
      'ngMaterial',
      'ngAnimate'        
  ])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider
          .when('/category', {
              templateUrl: _templateBase + '/category/category.html' ,
              controller: 'categoryController',
              controllerAs: '_ctrl'
          });
          $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
      }
  ]) ;    
  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider
          .when('/brands', {
              templateUrl: _templateBase + '/brands/brands.html' ,
              controller: 'brandsController',
              controllerAs: '_ctrl'
          });
          $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
      }
  ]) ;         
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve in such structure organizing. If you want to keep your routes related to components close to the related component it is enough to add config with routes to each folder (Your first example). In such case, you will not duplicate dependencies which presented across all modules.

**Example 1**:

```
 angular.module('app')
  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
          templateUrl: _templateBase + '/category/category.html' ,
          controller: 'categoryController',
          controllerAs: '_ctrl'
      });
      $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
  }
]) ;
```

And in case your components could grow in future with some subcomponents. You may want to create submodule for each, and attach config to them.

**Example 2**

```
 angular.module('app.brands', [])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
          templateUrl: _templateBase + '/category/category.html' ,
          controller: 'categoryController',
          controllerAs: '_ctrl'
      });
      $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
  }
]) ;
```

My personal feeling, that first example will work best for you. But you better know the domain of your app, so choose yourself. Anyway you should minimize dependencies injection which presented across all your project.